# Input Box inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, browser, iframe

I have an input box inside and iframe. If i type and press the back key to erase the text, the back key event is taken as browser back and goes to the previous page. What could be the cause.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please tell which browser you have tested with.

My guess would be that you have focus outside the field? is there a script putting focus on the document containing ths input box in the iframe?

Comment: The behavior is happening in both IE 7 and Firefox 3.0.10

Answer (score 0):

i even cann't raise same event. I press BackSpace in iframe, I press BackSpace in input, I press BackSpace in main page.
Which browser do you work with?
Is there any javascript code in the page?

Answer (score 0):

This is such an old browser behaviour. Update your browsers. In worst case scenario you can block the default events for the input element, using a jS library to get a unified response en browser events.